# Login con CURL y PHP al SII (Servicio impuestos internos de Chile) ya logueado

Tags: php, login, curl

Mediante `cUrl` y `php` logré acceder a SII con usuario y clave, obteniendo en un archivo las cookies, el token y el sessionid.

Lo que no logro es acceder con estos datos a otra de las paginas de SII.

Lo que intento es mediante este código obtener el informe de consumo de folios y enviar en la cabecera los datos de la cookie.

```
$data=array( 
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.rutm : xxxxxxx',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.dv  : x',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.dvm  : x',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.clave  : xxxxxxx',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.mac  : xxxxxxx',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.exp  : xxxxxxx',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.sec  : 0000',
    'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.lms  : 120',
    'TOKEN  : xxxxxxx',
    ' CSESSIONID : xxxxxxx',
    ' RUT_NS : xxxxxxx',
    ' DV_NS : x'
    );
    $ch1 = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://palena.sii.cl/cgi_dte/UPL/QEstCOFcont.sh?".
    "anoIni=2022&mesIni=01&anoFin=2022&mesFin=12&rutCons=$rut".
    "&dvCons=$dv&rutConsulta=$rut&dvConsulta=$dv&AREA=P");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$data);
      print_r($data); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,-1);
  
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $result  = curl_exec($ch1);
    $err     = curl_error($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);
    print_r($result);
    print_r($err);
```

El problema es que me da este error:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Thu, 06 Jan 2022 21:43:24 GMT Server:
> version 1.2 version 1.1 Apache Content-Security-Policy: default-src
> https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' Strict-Transport-Security:
> max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Content-Length: 9 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=iso-8859-1 Error 400

Mediante la consola de firefox, veo que la cookie de solicitud tiene valores que son los mismos que intento enviar en el header con un array y por supuesto reemplacé los valores por xxxx para mostrarlos en este foro.

¿Alguien tendrá una idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

De antemano,
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿intentaste hacer pruebas mediante aplicaciones como Postman? y otra pregunta ¿trabajas en ambiente Linux? yo he podido hacer pruebas pero a partir del shell, podría compartirte algo si es el caso.

Comment: Estimado, trabajo en linux centos, en postman reconoce los datos enviados, agradecería si pudiese compartir las pruebas que realizo en shell para comparar los parámetros que usted envió con lo que yo tengo. muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 problemas claves en su código.

1. Estás pasando los cookies como si fuera encabezados (headers).
2. Los cookies tienen formato de `<key>=<value>`, no `<key>:<value>`

Para solucionarlo, se debe pasar los valores de cookies a la opción `CURLOPT_COOKIE` como lo siguiente:

```php
// Lista de cookies
$cookies = array( 
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.rutm=xxxxxxx',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.dv=x',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.dvm=x',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.clave=xxxxxxx',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.mac=xxxxxxx',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.exp=xxxxxxx',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.sec=0000',
  'NETSCAPE_LIVEWIRE.lms=120',
  'TOKEN=xxxxxxx',
  'CSESSIONID=xxxxxxx',
  'RUT_NS=xxxxxxx',
  'DV_NS=x'
);

// Pasar el arreglo como cadena '<key>=<value>[; ...]' a CURLOPT_COOKIE
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode('; ', $cookies));
```